# Не могу установить xls

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xls

[image: ошибка установления]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('rasp.xls')
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

start_index = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   if row[0] == 'дни':
       start_index = index
       break
df = df[start_index:]
df.set_axis(df.loc[start_index], axis='columns', inplace=True)
df = df[1:]
df = df.T.drop_duplicates().T
df['дни'] = df['дни'].fillna(method='ffill')
df['часы'] = df['часы'].fillna(method='ffill')
#df.fillna('Нет пары', inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Пытаюсь парсить таблицу xls, но pycharm выдаёт ошибку

> 'ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'xlrd'. Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support Use pip or conda to install xlrd.'

Пытался подключить xlrd выдаёт

> 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlrd''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для чтения Excel файлов Pandas использует либо модуль `xlrd` (по умолчанию), либо `openpyxl`. Соответственно, эти модули должны быть установлены.

Устоновка модулей:

```
pip install xlrd xlwt openpyxl
```

или по одному:

```
pip install xlrd
pip install xlwt
pip install openpyxl
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!